# Fixed image size scale according content with background-size cover

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I have spent several days trying to find best way to display background image properly on different screen sizes.

Here is working example http://mobile-development.ru/. Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CROSP/pceva3pe/1/).
But it can be seen better on website.

The problem is following.
As you may see my initial image size is `1920x920`.
I have following `SASS` class for header image.

```
$header-min-height: 920px;
.l-header {
  min-height: $header-min-height;
  height: 110%;
  width: 100%;
  @include background-size(cover);
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image:url('../images/background-header.jpg');
  @include respond-to-less-than(desktops) {
    min-height: $header-min-height*1.6;

  }
  @include respond-to-less-than(tablets) {
    min-height: $header-min-height*1.8;
  }
}
```

Initial header background image looks good (not great but okay).
And content fits.

[image]

But when I screen size starts to decrease, because of `background-size` property image starts to scale. And furthermore as you can see for smaller screens I increase the `min-height` in order to fit content inside the image. 
Because on small screens items in row take full width.

[image]

And as you can see because of image scale and zoom quality of image becomes awful.

In case of square image I could take image with full height and display only part of it another part would be hidden under next div until required.

But in my case my image has rounded borders at the bottom, and I cannot achieve the same result using only CSS.

I want to get result like that

[image]

To make this picture I just cropped equal to the previous screenshot part of initial image.

Like that

[image]

I have no idea how to get desired result, to make image looks good on different screens. I've tried a lot of different tricks, but still as you see.

Please suggest what are possible ways to get desired result, is there only way to change different images according screen size (like `srcset`).
At worst on screens smaller than `990px` image could be without rounded corner.
I would be really grateful for any help of suggestion how to make it look good.

Big thanks.

Comment: Need more information. What is happening behind the scenes for the `background-size(cover)` property?

Comment: The problem is that `background-cover` makes image scale and quality becomes bad

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your layout generaly:

```css
.l-header {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../images/background-header.jpg);
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px)
.l-header {
    background-image: url(../new picture with portrait orienbtation);
}
.l-header-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.l-our-services {
    padding: 50px 0;
}
```

Remove this rules:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px)
.l-header {
    min-height: 1472px;
}
.l-our-services {
    padding-left: 0; 
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.l-header-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I see the only one way: to use another picture (with portrait orientation) for mobile layout. 
Your new picture must have height about 1500px for correct looking in your layout. Width - about 950px

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by changing the structure of your HTML in order to have a fixed background with the stars and the icons flowing on top of that.  As for the curved bottom edge I would use an SVG white element instead of having it on the image.

Something like this maybe:

```
<body>
    <section class="fixed_background"></section>
        <header id="header-main" class="header l-header container-fluid">
          Services content here...
        </header>
    <section class="curvedEdge"></section>
    <main id="main-content" class="main-content l-main-content">
          Some other content here
    </main>
    <footer id="footer-main" class="footer-main l-footer-main">
</footer>
</body>
```

[Check this JSFiddle fork](https://jsfiddle.net/zjorge/tmrj59j5/) from yours I did.  Is not polished but thats the idea. I emptied `.l-header` and added new CSS rules are at the end.